# fit a gumbel copula to 500 set generated random number

Tags: copula, gumbel-distribution

i have a question, of finding the tail coefficient of gumbel copula. I generated 500 set of random variable, with 4 different theta of 1, 1.5, 2 and 3. Then I fit them to gumbel copula with maximum likelihood method. for each theta, i generated these:

theta=1
Copula: gumbelCopula 
alpha 
    1 
The maximized loglikelihood is -3.838e-07

theta =1.5
Copula: gumbelCopula 
alpha 
 1.46 
The maximized loglikelihood is 83.3

theta = 2
Copula: gumbelCopula 
alpha 
 1.93 
The maximized loglikelihood is 187

theta = 3
Copula: gumbelCopula 
alpha 
 2.88 
The maximized loglikelihood is 359

but how do i find the tail coefficients to each Gumbel copula with each theta? Also what does the maximized loglikelihood refers to?